# SVG not rendering properly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, web, svg

I have a problem with SVG renderring in Firefox. Whilst it works in Safari, Chrome or even in IE, it doesn't work in Firefox. Inspecting the element it seems that the layers are there, but only background is visible as if it's z-index is higher than the z-index of the others.

Rendered in Firefox:
[SVG logo in Firefox](https://mediacru.sh/LoZlJt5kRMCc)

Link to the original source file: [SVG File](https://mediacru.sh/7_yW-F5DT16J)

Thanks for your help.

PS: I used Sketch 3 to export the svg. If it helps somehow.

Comment: If I open it with Inkscape, it shows just like in Firefox. You probably used some proprietary feature or some quirk that is not generally supported.

Comment: No, it's an actual honest to goodness bug in Firefox. You should report it as a bug in Inkscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're experiencing [bug 995813](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=995813).

I fixed this bug some time ago but that change is still making its way through the release process so your example will display correctly from Firefox 31 onwards which will be released on 22 July 2014.

In the meantime if you move the fill="white" from the `<mask>` element to the child `<use>` element this will work around the Firefox bug.