# SVG is not being rendered in Firefox 34.0.5 and IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am working on a website where I am using a lot of SVG elements. Now lately I have seen that the elements are being rendered in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m and Opera. However, that is not the case with Firefox Version 34.0.5 and Internet Explorer 11. I have checked this answer

[SVG not rendering properly in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608740/svg-not-rendering-properly-in-firefox) ,

According to the above answer it says that this is a bug in FF 16 however they have resolved it in the latest versions of FF even in IE11 and as far as my research goes, SVG is not an issue with IE11.
Now the strange thing is that all the simple SVG files are being rendered however a complex vector file such as a vector of iPhone 5 is not rendered **ONLY** in IE and FF. Below is an SVG thats not working in FF or IE:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="210px" height="211.5px" viewBox="0 0 210 211.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 210 211.5;" xml:space="preserve">

<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#FF5200;}
.st1{fill:none;stroke:#FF5200;stroke-width:7;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>

<filter id="drop">
   <feOffset result = "offOut" in = "#ff5500" dx = "0" dy = "0"/>
   <feGaussianBlur result = "blurOut" in = "offOut" stdDeviation = "4"/>
    <feBlend in = "SourceGraphic" in2 = "blurOut" mode = "normal"/>
</filter>

<g id="bolt">
<polygon filter="url(#drop)" class="st0" points="138.1,42.5 63.9,116.3 105.2,116.3 70.2,172.3 146.3,98.5 105.1,98.5     "/>
```

Click [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yk20q8sn/2/) So you can get a better understanding of the issue.

I created the SVG in Illusrator CS6. So my question is Whats the phenomena here ? What mistake am I doing here ? Is this is a bug in IE and FF ? I am using SVG because I want to incorporate some SVG animations. Are there any good Fallbacks for this issue to be solved ? Can I get some good resources regarding this specific issue ? I apologize if this information is not sufficient, as I am a beginner in SVG animation hence I am open for advices, criticism etc as I am in the learning phase. If there is any extra information required please let me know and I will respond.

EDIT: Please check [**the Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yk20q8sn/2/)  in FF, IE and Chrome to see the difference.

Thanks for your Help !

Comment: How would we know what mistake you are doing unless you show us the markup that isn't working? Please add a small example to your question.

Comment: @RobertLongson here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk20q8sn/2/) of SVG. You will understand clearly what I am talking about.

Comment: @ZubairPyromaniac - Firefox does not like your filter attributes. For example, remove the attribute "filter=url(#drop)" from your bolt and outcircle elements towards the bottom of your fiddle.

Comment: This is a Chrome bug. Do report it to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @RobertLongson How is it a bug if it works in chrome ? Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Because given the markup you have what Firefox and IE do is correct per the SVG specification and what Chrome does is incorrect. The SVG specification says what should happen, if that's not what you expect, get the specification changed. Until then Chrome has a bug as it's not following the SVG specification.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the elaboration ! I understood now what you mean, so Chrome being right was actually wrong... LOL xD thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of your filter :
Change this line `<feOffset result = "offOut" in = "#000000" dx = "0" dy = "10"/>` to this one `<feOffset result = "offOut" in = "SourceGraphic" dx = "0" dy = "10"/>`

And it will work.

You were telling the filter to go from a color instead of a filter-primitive (check http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#FilterPrimitiveInAttribute)

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk20q8sn/7/)

Comment: Thanks A lot !!! It works now in FF and IE, just a Keyword messed up my workflow, anyways I checked out the link however I dint understand the FillPaint keyword, how to apply it ?, if you could give me a small example, it would be really gratful of YOU !!! Thanks again.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20110816/harness/htmlObjectApproved/filters-overview-01-b.html

Comment: Interestingly FF doesn't pass cases 3 & 4 (35.0 beta on osx9)