# Firefox not rendering svg properly

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I came with this issue in Firefox, or maybe I'm using something wrong, but I use svg images like this:

```
<img src="image.svg" alt="some image">
```

And the browser rendering them like this:

[image]

I can have them like `.png`  and it works fine, but I need them in `.svg`

**Update with SVG source**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <defs>
        <path id="a" d="M13.333 9.333V7.746c0-.717.159-1.08 1.271-1.08H16V4h-2.33c-2.853 0-3.795 1.308-3.795 3.554v1.78H8V12h1.875v8h3.458v-8h2.35L16 9.333h-2.667z"/>
        <path id="c" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <mask id="b" fill="#fff">
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </mask>
        <use fill="#000" xlink:href="#a"/>
        <g mask="url(#b)">
            <use fill="#232323" xlink:href="#c"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Update 2**

Tried to move the `fill` attribute from `<mask>` to its child element `<use>` just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608740/svg-not-rendering-properly-in-firefox) question, and didn't fixed the issue. 
I'm using Firefox 55.0.3.

Comment: They're rendered:is the problem and the question about poor rendering quality?

Comment: Seems fine with this svg as an element (Fx on Win10). Do you see any difference between `img[src="*.svg"]` and `<svg>`?

Comment: @FelipeAls still the same. rendering it poorly

Comment: can't repro on FF56 https://jsfiddle.net/1oym0uny/

Comment: See no issue. Please clarify.

Comment: @cs.matyi it's working properly in my Firefox browser on Maca and I have edited your Question and inserted the code properly so please approve it so all of us can check.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVG not rendering properly in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608740/svg-not-rendering-properly-in-firefox)

Comment: @Kaiido I opened your jsfiddle, and rendering here poorly  too in FF.
BTW I'm using FF 55.0.3

Comment: I am also seeing a problem in FF 55.0.3 with both the dataURI *and* inline. https://jsfiddle.net/1oym0uny/1/  However it renders okay in the StackOverflow version for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why FF is having a problem with this file. You may want to report this as bug to them.

Luckily there is a simple fix. Get rid of those somewhat unnecessary masks that Illustrator adds.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M13.333 9.333V7.746c0-.717.159-1.08 1.271-1.08H16V4h-2.33c-2.853 0-3.795 1.308-3.795 3.554v1.78H8V12h1.875v8h3.458v-8h2.35L16 9.333h-2.667z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>svg fix</title>
    <style>
        .icon {
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;

        }
        .icon path {
            fill:#000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="icon" src="icon-fixed.svg" alt="fixed SVG">
<!--PUT BELOW CODE IN NEW DOCUMENT AND SAVE AS icon-fixed.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M13.3,9.3V7.7c0-0.7,0.2-1.1,1.3-1.1H16V4h-2.3c-2.9,0-3.8,1.3-3.8,3.6v1.8H8V12h1.9v8h3.5v-8h2.4L16,9.3H13.3z" />
</svg>-->
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I would use them (allways used them before), but our UI team liked to use their own icons instead and don't have time to argue with them right now...

Comment: The icons look like standard issue? If you are in a rush just put the svg code directly in the page. Ask them to tidy up the crap from the Illustrator file so you only have the bare required paths. Also I suggest making the svg maybe half to one pixel smaller than the canvas then center vertical & horizontal. I have had some minor clipping in the past where the path goes right to the very edges.
So the canvas size is say 24px X 24px but the path is 23px X 23px. Hope this makes sense?

Good luck with the UI team mate.

Comment: Tried it also, Sadly it is not working. Thank you by the way!